# Why does vga and dvi have screws when most other connectors do not?

Tags: vga, dvi, hotplug

I know that a question like this exists, but the answer is not what I was looking for.

Do vga/dvi have screws because they are not hotpluggable? Why would they not be hotpluggable (surge issues?) Also, would a kvm be dangerous for a computer/monitor since they are not hotpluggable?

Answer (score 7):

They're just there to stop them falling out of the sockets.

A lot of the older D-type connector like serial, parallel and SCSI ports have them.

The cable coming out is relatively heavy and is easy to knock out, hence the screws.

Comment: Ditto for HDMI, which sometimes comes with screws for the same reason.   http://i.ebayimg.com/t/HDMI-Screw-Terminal-Adapter-/00/s/MjEzWDU2Nw==/$%28KGrHqIOKokE5lKJ2jf9BOb1D5f1yg~~60_12.JPG

Comment: Any answers about hotplugging?

Comment: Hotplugging issues vary.  it is often just that the OS can't see the new device without a reboot.  A USB KVM won't be a problem, as USB is hotpluggable.

Comment: @parkydr with USB it can only be KM